# How can I use ssh -X on macOS Catalina? [Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated]

Tags: catalina, ssh, macports, x11

How do I get ssh -X working on macOS Catalina (10.15)?

`ssh -X linux_host` works from another linux machine.

On a fresh install of macOS Catalina, I have installed MacPorts and xorg_server. However, `ssh -X linux_host` gives the following error message:

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

In attempt to get this working, I changed my ~/.ssh/config file to

```
Protocol 2
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation /opt/local/bin/xauth
```

however this seems to make no difference.

Please note that `ssh -Y` works but is less secure than `ssh -X`.

Comment: Try `ssh -Y`...